# Magento set base currency - geoip lookup

Tags: php, magento, geoip

I'm trying to set the currency based on IP lookup.

So far I've found only this php snippet for setting the currency http://ravikumar85.blogspot.ie/2010/02/magento-set-base-currency-through-code.html

but if I put this code in index.php just before Mage::run()

```
if($geolookup == 'UK') {
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('GBP');
}
```

I get this error

```
There has been an error processing your request
Mage registry key "controller" already exists
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: This http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-currency-switcher-1.html may help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the reason you wish to have the custom modification. Anyway, modify the app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php by adding the below code will work you the solution.

```
public function getCurrentCurrencyCode()
{
  if($geolookup == 'UK') {
      $this->_getSession()->setCurrencyCode('GBP');
  }

  ......
 }
```